# Material UI - React Router - BreadCrumbs with ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, breadcrumbs

i'm trying to implement material ui breadcrumbs integrated with reactRouter but i'm having a small problem,

```
const breadcrumbNameMap = {
  '/users': 'Users',
  '/users/:id': ':id',
  '/users/:id/detail': 'Details',
}
```

and then the component from the material ui example:

```
      <NoSsr>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/stock']} initialIndex={0}>
          <div >
            <Route>
              {({ location }) => {
                const pathnames = this.props.location.pathname.split('/').filter(x => x)

                return (
                  <Breadcrumbs arial-label="Breadcrumb">
                    {/* <Link component={RouterLink} color="inherit" to="/stocks">
                      Home
                    </Link> */}
                    {pathnames.map((value, index) => {
                      const last = index === pathnames.length - 1;
                      const to = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}`;
                      return last ? (
                        <Typography color="textPrimary" key={to}>
                          {breadcrumbNameMap[to]}
                        </Typography>
                      ) : (
                        <Link component={RouterLink} color="inherit" to={to} key={to}>
                          {breadcrumbNameMap[to]}
                        </Link>
                      )
                    })}
                  </Breadcrumbs>
                )
              }}
            </Route>
          </div>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </NoSsr>
```

What happens is since ':id' is not specified the script can't find the correct string to put in the breadcrumb. (if i specify the ID it works as expected)

is there any way to pass :id as props to the breadcrumbs so i can display the full routes with ID's?

Comment: Change {breadcrumbNameMap[to]} to value. Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511033/10908140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of location you can use `match` i.e. `match.params.id`

Comment: I understand that but how can i pass params to that variable? turn it into a function that returns the variable?

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4556. I would try the last answer as it's the simplest. Also from that thread someone made a HOC: https://github.com/icd2k3/react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc